# Fake DB on Sitecore.data.Items.Item.add method

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

I'm creating a unit test for a code that has an Item.Add method used and trying to use Sitecore Fake DB for this and I'm getting an error that it's not being populated.

A sample code below:

```
public class SampleTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void SampleTest_GetNewItem()
    {
        var myHomeID = new ID();
        var templateID = new ID();
        var template = new TemplateID(templateID);

        using (var db = new Db()
        {
            new DbItem("Home", myHomeID)
        }){
            Item myHomeItem = db.GetItem(myHomeID);
            Item returnItem = myHomeItem.Add("myNewItem", template);

            returnItem.Should().NotBeNull(); //Assert fails because returnItem is null
        }
    }
}
```

Is this behavior not supported by fake DB? or is there something wrong with the code? and how can the code be unit tested?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add template to the `FakeDB` database first.

Just add those 2 lines to your code:

```
var childTemplate = new DbTemplate("child", templateID);
db.Add(childTemplate);
```

e.g:

```
var myHomeID = new ID();
var templateID = new ID();
var template = new TemplateID(templateID);

using (var db = new Db {new DbItem("Home", myHomeID)})
{
    var childTemplate = new DbTemplate("child", templateID);
    db.Add(childTemplate);

    Item myHomeItem = db.GetItem(myHomeID);
    Item returnItem = myHomeItem.Add("myNewItem", template);

    returnItem.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this works perfectly. I guess I didn't pay attention to the template being non-existent in the fake db.